# Can I add device to HomeKit without iPhone with macOS only?

Tags: macos, homekit, monterey

Is it possible to add new homekit device with access to only apple laptop?
All tutorials I found mentioned about using iOS.

I searched "Home" app in macOS but I can only add and edit rooms and people, not hardware like sensors etc.

I'm also curious if iOS is required, can I use iOS emulator in Xcode as a workaround?
I'm not planning to buy iPhone and MacBook Air M1 with macOS Monterey 12.0.1 is my first and only apple device.

Comment: What macOS are you running? Functionality has changed over time.

Comment: Thanks for asking, I updated the question.
I'm using latest OS when I'm writing this.

Comment: I've never used Homekit myself, but have a look at https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/home/hmeb738f98cf/6.0/mac/12.0 for starters.

Comment: Unfortunately, apple guide didn't mentioned adding devices, only controlling already added ones.

Comment: Ahh… "You can't add accessories to the Home app on Mac." https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204893 idk about on Xcode. Hope someone can help.